# Redux Form is not displaying on React Bootstrap Modal when other redux action creator was called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I use React Bootstrap modal to show `Redux-Form` on a popup and it's working fine if I simply use state to show/hide the modal but when I tried to show/hide the modal using `Redux` action creator, the popup didn't show at all.

I was able to display anything on the modal when I show/hide from `Redux` action creator but not from the `Redux-Form`.

Here is my Form config,

```
LoginForm = reduxForm({
form: 'LoginForm',
validate,
})(LoginForm);
```

Here is what I'm seeing from my console,

```
action @ 03:21:49.866 OPEN_LONGIN_MODAL

core.js:97 action @ 03:21:49.916 @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS
core.js:97 action @ 03:21:49.935 @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD
core.js:97 action @ 03:21:49.957 @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD
core.js:97 action @ 03:21:49.994 @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS
core.js:97 action @ 03:21:50.320 @@redux-form/DESTROY
```

If I add, "destroyOnUnmount: false", it looks like this

```
core.js:97 action @ 03:12:10.746 OPEN_LONGIN_MODAL
core.js:97 action @ 03:12:10.798 @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS
core.js:97 action @ 03:12:10.815 @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD
core.js:97 action @ 03:12:10.839 @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD
core.js:97 action @ 03:12:10.873 @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It was nothing to do with Redux Form, I made a mistake in my reducer that causes the modal to close when Redux form started registering the fields.